# C# NAudio: How to access the samples provided by SignalGenerator in order to save them to WAVE format?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wave

I have the following constructor, which successfully plays pink noise directly to my audio output device:

```
public WAVEManager(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
{
        IWavePlayer outputDevice;
        outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();

        SignalGenerator pinkNoiseGenerator = new SignalGenerator();
        pinkNoiseGenerator.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Pink;
        outputDevice.Init(pinkNoiseGenerator);
        outputDevice.Play();

        // Wait for 10 seconds
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

This all works fine. I understand that now if I want to write to a .wav, I have to initialise a WaveFileWriter like so:

```
WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFileName, pinkNoiseGenerator.WaveFormat);
```

And then write to the created WAVE file:

```
writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, numSamples);
```

The rub being that I have no idea how to populate the `buffer` directly from `pinkNoiseGenerator`. I have searched through the documentation and examples and can't find anything to do with this - I imagine it must involve the `.Read()` method of the `SignalGenerator` class, but as the generator plays indefinitely, it has no defined length. To me, this means that the `buffer` can't be populated in the same way it could if we were, say, reading directly from an input WAVE file (as far as I can tell).

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can create a WAV file containing 10 seconds of pink noise:

```
var pinkNoiseGenerator = new SignalGenerator();
pinkNoiseGenerator.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Pink;
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16("pinkNoise.wav", pinkNoiseGenerator.Take(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
```

Comment: Cheers mush! For the next stage I will actually need to access the samples directly to multiply them by a variable gain factor. Most efficient just to use the WaveFileReader on the created .wav for this, or is there a way to do it as an intermediate step in the above solution?

Comment: just wrap the signal generator in a `VolumeSampleProvider` ... or even easier, use the `Gain` property on the `SignalGenerator` itself